# Log4j2.xml Invalid URI File Warning

Tags: spring, log4j

I have a spring boot maven project and I'm using log4j.

My configuration file is at src/main/resources/log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <!-- Console appender configuration -->
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When I run my spring boot project, I am getting this error:
`main WARN Invalid URI file://<path-to-project>/target/classes/log4j2.xml`

I think this error is preventing my configuration file from being used.
What's causing this error and how can I resolve it?